# PowerShell sorting

Tags: powershell, sorting

I have the following folders under C:\Temp:

"folder 1"
"folder 10"
"folder 2"
"folder 3"
"folder 11"

I want to sort them in the order:

"folder 1" -> "folder 2" -> "folder 3" -> "folder 10" -> "folder 11"

However with the command `Get-ChildItem C:\Temp -Directory | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name | Sort-Object` I get:

"folder 1" -> "folder 10" -> "folder 11" -> "folder 2" -> "folder 3"

How do I fix this without modifying the folder names? Thanks

Comment: Thanks. I thought there was a perfect answer but now it looks like there isn't. Looks like renaming the folders with 01 02 03 etc is the only way to address it without making it more complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[js2010's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64198469/45375) works, as long as file names have the *same prefix*, such as `folder` .

- Note: As he also points out, fixing the problem at the *source*, by left-padding the numbers in the embedded names e.g., `folder 1` -> `folder 0001`, is probably the better option, because then `Get-ChildItem` will automatically list them in the desired order. However, (a) that assumes you're free to rename those folders and (b) you need to choose a wide-enough padding to accommodate future folders (have a sense of how large the count of folders is allowed to grow over time) and (c) if future folders are *manually* named, care must be taken to get the padding right.

The following is a ***generalized* solution that works with all file names that end in a decimal number *whatever their prefix***, and also sorts other names properly:

```
# Simulate Get-ChildItem output
[IO.FileInfo[]] $files = 
  "folder 1", "folder 10", "folder 2", "folder 3", "folder 11", 
  "zfolder 10", "zfolder 1", 
  "afolder 10", "afolder 1",
  "nonumberhere"

($files | 
  Sort-Object { 
    $n = $_.Name; try { '{0}{1,10}' -f ($_.Name -split '(\d+$)') } catch { $n }
  }
).Name
```

Note: If you really want just *strings* (names) as input, change `$n = $_.Name` to `$n = $_` above, and omit `(...).Name`.

The solution is based on dynamically left-padding the trailing numbers (with spaces) to `10` characters (which is the widest a positive `[int]` value can get), which ensures that *lexical* sorting effectively amounts to sorting by the non-numeric prefix first, and then by the *numeric* value of the suffix.
For instance, `'folder 10'` is transformed to `'folder        10'` for the purpose of sorting.

The above yields:

```
afolder 1
afolder 10
folder 1
folder 2
folder 3
folder 10
folder 11
nonumberhere
zfolder 1
zfolder 10
```

---

You can wrap the code above in a simple function:

```
function sort-FileName {
  $Input | Sort-Object {
    $n = $_.Name; try { '{0}{1,10}' -f ($_.Name -split '(\d+$)') } catch { $n }
  }
}
```

This would then allow you to call:

```
(Get-ChildItem C:\Temp -Directory | sort-FileName).Name
```

Answer (score 2):

I would rename them so there's 01 02 03 etc.  Anyway, the replace just has the numbers remaining, then it's cast to integer for the sort.  I figured it out using foreach first.

```
# mkdir 'folder 1','folder 10','folder 2','folder 3','folder 11'
# dir | % { [int]($_.name -replace '[a-z ]*(\d*)','$1') }
dir | sort { [int]($_.name -replace '[a-z ]*(\d*)','$1') }


    Directory: C:\Users\js\foo

Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
d----           10/4/2020  2:29 PM                folder 1
d----           10/4/2020  2:29 PM                folder 2
d----           10/4/2020  2:29 PM                folder 3
d----           10/4/2020  2:29 PM                folder 10
d----           10/4/2020  2:29 PM                folder 11
```